# Native JPA query to select with joining tables and same column name

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, nativequery

I have two tables, account and accountEmail

Table: account
-(accountID, emailAddress, firstName, lastName)

- 101, hello@gmail.com, first, last

Table: accountEmail

- (accountEmailID, accountID, emailAddress, type, confirmed)
- 101, 101, hello@gmail.com,1,1
- 102, 101, hello_alternate@gmail.com,2,1

Issue: Searching for "hello@gmail.com" and "hello_alternate@gmail.com"
result contains 2 elements, but both the elements have same values

```
  Actual  Result:
{
        "emailAddress": "hello_alternate@gmail.com",
        "name": "Test User",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "User",
        "id": "1000001",
        "userEmailAddress": "hello@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "hello_alternate@gmail.com",
        "name": "Test User",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "User",
        "id": "1000001",
        "userEmailAddress": "hello@gmail.com"
    }
}

Expected Result:
{
        "emailAddress": "hello@gmail.com",
        "name": "Test User",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "User",
        "id": "1000001",
        "userEmailAddress": "hello@gmail.com"
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "hello_alternate@gmail.com",
        "name": "Test User",
        "firstName": "Test",
        "lastName": "User",
        "id": "1000001",
        "userEmailAddress": "hello@gmail.com"
    }
}



    public interface SearchRepository extends JpaRepository<AccountDetails, Long>, ISearchRepository {
    @Nonnull
    @Query(value = "SELECT account.accountID, account.emailAddress, account.firstName," +
            " account.lastName, accountEmail.emailAddress as accountEmailAddress" +
            " FROM account account" +
            " JOIN accountEmail accountEmail ON account.accountID = accountEmail.accountID" +
            " WHERE accountEmail.emailAddress IN ?1" +
            " LIMIT " + MAXIMUM_QUERY_SIZE, nativeQuery = true)
        List<AccountDetails> findAllByEmailAddressIn(@Nonnull Collection<String> emails);
}






@Table(name = "account")
@SecondaryTable(name = "accountEmail")
Class AccountDetails {

    @Id
    @ToString.Include
    @Column(name = "accountID", table = "account")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "emailAddress", table = "account")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "firstName", table = "account")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName", table = "account")
    private String lastName;


    @Column(name = "accountEmailAddress", table = "accountEmail")
    private String userEmailAddress;
}
```

Comment: The query is asked to build entities, but you haven’t returned the ID values in the data. This makes the two rows appear to be for the same entities (null id), so you get two references to the same managed account detail instance. Return the id value and it’ll work- but there is no need for a native query here. Just use “select a from AccountDetails a where a. userEmailAddress In :emailList” and let spring handle pagination (limit) on the query for you

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Chris. 

Can you please specify which ID you are talking about?

Comment: AccountDetails is mapped as an entity with an id annotation (to accountId) that you aren’t returning. Best practice is to return everything you’ve mapped in your entity or the lack of data will cause the app issues when it tries making modifications (and for caching)